# AndEngine - Difference between onAccelerometerChanged and onAccelerationChanged

Tags: android, box2d, andengine

Please forgive me for my ignorance. I'm just starting out using the AndEngine and I've been trying to comprehend the difference between the 2 methods;

- onAccelerometerChanged(AccelerometerData pAccelerometerData)
- onAccelerationChanged(final AccelerationData pAccelerationData)

Both are used for moving a sprite along the Axes with the Accelerometer. One thing I know by know is that the onAccelerationChanged method comes from the Box2d extension but what's the main difference between the two? Does the Box2D method only allows for special settings such as a linear damping coefficient or such? Or are there more elementary differences between the two.

(For more experienced AndEngine users: the Physics example makes use of the Box2d physics extension. I have found no other until now that uses the other method.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that onAccelerometerChanged is used in Andengine-GLES1, and onAccelerationChanged is used in Andengine-GLES2.